# Are Push Notifications still delivered if an app has been force-stopped

Tags: android, ios, drupal

I am working on a client site where we are using Drupal for the backend and have recently implemented the [Push Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/push_notifications) module to handle messaging to users of the clients app from the App/Play stores.

All has been working fine for a number of weeks with tests performed and many messages sent.

Now when attempting to send notifications the system returns the 'success message':

> Successfully sent 26 iOS push messages (attempted to send 26 messages).
>
> Successfully sent 0 Android push messages (attempted to send 106 messages).

I came across something on the Android Developers forum at http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols and at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-gcm/MqVlA3Sj26c/uO-ttsXOyy0J and https://www.parse.com/questions/problem-with-push-notification-where-android-apps-force-stop.

From what I can understand they are saying that after a user force-stops an app that notifications are not received until the next time the app is started.

If this is correct then my 'attempted' messages count does not mean that the push/send is broken on the site but is likely that users uninstalled the app or have force-closed it.

Is this correct?

Would love to hear anyones thoughts or recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I can understand they are saying that after a user force-stops an app that notifications are not received until the next time the app is started.

Assuming that this system is using GCM, that is a correct assessment.

> If this is correct then my 'attempted' messages count does not mean that the push/send is broken on the site but is likely that users uninstalled the app or have force-closed it.

You would have to ask the authors of whatever it is that you are using that question. It could be that there is some configuration problem whereby the system is incapable of reaching Google's servers, for example.

Comment: It is using GCM and has a valid Google Cloud Messaging API Key (as far as I am aware)

Comment: I have also contacted the author of the Push Notifications module and posted to the modules issue queue.